# Problems executing Fortran in a cluster queue

Tags: linux, bash, fortran, cluster-computing, fortran90

I have problems loading a fortran code in a cluster queue. The admind have installed two versions of Fortran.
To have access to "ifort" commmand I must load the intel module.

This is my PATH varible after loading the module:

```
/share/apps/openmpi-intel-mx/bin:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/064/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/bin/intel64:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:
```

Then I compile my code without problems.

I wrote a script to submit into a queue:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -V
#PBS -l nodes=1
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l walltime=05:00
#PBS -N NaN0
#PBS -q physics

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
module load intel

./model
```

Then it returns a error:
    ./model: /opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so: no version information available (required by ./model)

I don't know how to solve it. It is not supposed use this compiler, because it is the second on the PATH.

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure that this message is an error, not a warning? Can you check `PATH` in every node? Have you read this [solution](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/269634)?

Comment: @Andrey Thank you for the answer. the Path is the same. I add echo $PATH into the script, and "echoes" the same PATH as my user

Comment: As a work-around, you can try `ifort ... -openmp-link static`.

Comment: @Andrey this flag does not exist.

Comment: I don't have access to v. 11.1, but `-openmp-link static` should be available (search for Intel's "Document Number: 304970-006US", I cannot provide a direct link because this part of intel.com is down right now). Anyway, after the compilation you can check all required libraries with `ldd model`. If the path to `libiomp5.so` is correct, then you can try `LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/.../libiomp5.so ./model` to force particular library to be used during program execution. If this works on a compilation node, but fails on other nodes, it's possible that library paths are different.

Comment: @Andrey it returns :
ERROR: ld.so: object '/opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/064/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so' from                                              LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

Comment: ./model: /opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so: no version information available (required by ./model)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000360ec00000)
        libiomp5.so => /opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so (0x00002b3d39c46000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000038fae00000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000360e800000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003620600000)

Comment: It is strange, because this is 11.0 version, which is the second of the path, when I'm compiling how can I specify which Fortran version should ifort use?

Comment: You can specify an absolute path to the ifort, e.g. `/opt/intel/.../ifort`. Also you should check other environment variables to be sure that all the libraries/components are of the same version (see `man ifort` for details). During compilation use `ifort -v` to see the exact file names used by ifort.

Answer (score 0):

Run-time library lookups do not use `PATH`, but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Add this to the file where you define your path:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/share/apps/openmpi-intel-mx/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

(It's not clear from your question what the correct directory is, so I took a guess. Use the directory under `/share/apps/openmpi-intel-mx` that actually contains `libiomp5.so`.)

Comment: I've tried this, and I've got the same error:
/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so: no version information available

Comment: `ldd model` on the compilation node will provide a correct path. Also it's possible to use `LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/.../libiomp5.so ./model` to force particular library to be used during the program execution.